# TableView Background image going over cell textLabel

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Currently my tableview looks like this: [image: this is my current view] as you can see, cell.textLabel and cell.detailTextLable both load this background, and i can't work out how to get them to stop loading the background, and for it only to be the backing on the cell.

Here's my current code to change the cell:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableCell.png"]]];
}
```

How can i get round this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `[[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:blabla];` ?